# logstash as service - no logs reaching elasticsearch

Tags: logstash

I have the kibana web app running, but it shows an index from last week.
How can I get a new index loaded for today's date? is it as a result of logging?
If so, then I must not be contacting the logstash server.

I followed this article:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04

Is there anyway to run diagnostics when running as a service?
Any command lines I issue to the service?

Here is my logstash config:

```
input {
  tcp {
    type => "apache"
    port => 3333
  }


}

filter {
  if [type] == "apache" {
    grok {

      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }

   date {

      match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {

    embedded => true
  }

}
```

Comment: there are command line flags you can use for to diagnose the configuration better. Use this (`--verbose`) flag while starting the service and start it in foreground using `-f` to see if there is an error.

Comment: --verbose does not add any additional information.

Comment: Can you query your ES cluster and see if all the new indexes you are looking for are being created and/or exists or not?

Comment: That's the thing. Im trying to add more events to see if they are grtting received. I need a way to test sending.events command line using the service. When I try to use the scripts in the service folder, it runs but there is no info returned.

Comment: There are a lot of steps between the logfiles and kibana.  Here's an article that hits on debugging them:  http://svops.com/blog/?p=26

Comment: I am defintely able to send events while on the localhost. I need to see if I can connect remotely to logstash. My CURL and NC operations say the logstash server is hit-able remotely, I just need to diagnose the logstash-forwarder script. when I run dpkg on it, it's installed ok, seems to be running. just not connecting to the logstash server.

Comment: Is there any way to send events remotely via command line?

Comment: I believe the logstash 'tcp' input will accept messages in any format.  You could listen with that and then curl post messages to it.